# remove item from cart

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to remove an item from the cart

this is my view cart in blade

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $total = 0; ?>
    @foreach ($cart as $item)
    <?php 
    $id=$item['id'];
    /* dd($id); */
    $total += $item['price'] * $item['qty']; ?>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $item['name'] }}</td>
      <td>${{ $item['price'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item['qty'] }}</td>
      <td><a href="{{route('cart.cartDelete', $id)}}">Cancella</a></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my controller

```
class CartEcommerceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $cart = session()->get('cart');
        if ($cart == null)
            $cart = [];
        /* dd($cart); */
            
        return view('cart.cart')->with('cart', $cart);
    }

    public function deleteItemCart($id){

        $cart = Session()->get('cart');
        $itemDelete=$cart[$id]['id'];
        dd($itemDelete);
        unset($cart[$id]);
        session()->put('cart', $cart);
        if (count($cart)==0) {
            session()->forget('cart');

        }

        return redirect()->back();

    }
    
    
}
```

when i click on delete i can pass the id but it does not enter the controller
and it returns me a page with 404 error page not found

this is my route

```
Route::post('cart/delete/{$id}', [CartEcommerceController::class,'deleteItemCart'])->name('cart.cartDelete');
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: remove name & check

Comment: didn't work, always the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are passing variable inthe route

```
Route::post('cart/delete/{id}', [CartEcommerceController::class,'deleteItemCart'])->name('cart.cartDelete');
```